# Prolog why these 2 items unify?

Tags: list, prolog

I'm very confused as to why [a,b,c,d] and [a,b|[c,d]] unify. From my limited understanding, the "|" operator splits the head and tail producing [a,b] and [[c,d]]. So how can this result object with apparent double list unify with the c,d, of the first one?

Comment: you can test how the unification operator (=)/2 behaves with `?- [a,b,c,d]=[a,b|T]. T = [c, d].`. No double lists there !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lists `[a,b,c,d]` and `[a,b|[c,d]]` are the same thing, the "|" splits the list to the head `a` and Tail which is `[b,c,d]` (see @Will Ness's comment). Take a look below to understand it better:

```
[a,b,c] unifies with [Head|Tail] resulting in Head=a and Tail=[b,c]

[a] unifies with [H|T] resulting in H=a and T=[]

[a,b,c] unifies with [a|T] resulting in T=[b,c]

[a,b,c] doesn't unify with [b|T]

[] doesn't unify with [H|T]

[] unifies with []. Two empty lists always match
```

In the second example you can see that `[a]` is same to `[a|[]]`, and in the third example: `[a,b,c]` is unifying with `[a|[b,c]]` which is same to your example.

Comment: "the `|` splits the list to the head `[a,b]` and tail `[c,d]`" -- no. try `[a,b,c,d] =.. X.`, `[a|[b,c,d]] =.. Y.`, `[a|[b|[c,d]]] =.. Z.`  to see what's going on.

Comment: @Will Ness, sorry for the late reply, you have right, your comment was very helpful and important, I edited the answer, thank you !!!

Comment: glad to help. :)